# Stripe Subscriptions Showing Nul

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am searching subscription data by customer for Stripe, even in multiple ways, and the data for that aspect is coming back null. In my test Stripe environment, I have a customer who clearly has a subscription attached to it, and it is clear from the Stripe dashboard. On my webapp, I try to pull the subscription and it's data by entering email, which finds the customer ID, which then finds the subscription data. But it always comes as null and it shouldn't. I am using C# in an ASP.NET web app.

```
void Go(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_mysecretkey";
            var options = new CustomerSearchOptions
            {
                Query = "email:'isaacsurban@gmail.com'",
            };
            options.AddExpand("subscriptions");
            options.AddExpand("customer.subscriptions");
            var service = new CustomerService();
            service.Search(options);
            Message.Text = service.Search(options).ToString();
}
```

The above code returns a bunch of data, but the subscription field is null.
And I have other code, where I simply hard code the customer ID to get nothing but thew subscription data and it too gives results, but says there are no subscriptions.

```
void GetSubs(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_mysecretkey";

            var options = new SubscriptionSearchOptions
            {
              Query = "metadata['customer']:'cus_mycustid'",
            };
            var service = new SubscriptionService();
            service.Search(options);
            Message2.Text = service.Search(options).ToString();
        }
```

I cant discern why the subscriptions would be empty, I am not sure if there is a search option I need to add, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Even searching from the stripe client webpage give a null result

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to expand the `subscriptions` attribute on the Customer objects you get back from using Stripe's search APIs, then you're using the wrong expansion property.

Instead of `options.AddExpand("customer.subscriptions");` you need to do `options.AddExpand("data.subscriptions");`. You can read more about expanding properties in lists [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#lists)

Comment: It worked, thank you. I was on the right track, I just misunderstood and didn't put the "data" in there.

Answer (score 0):

'Instead of options.AddExpand("customer.subscriptions"); you need to do options.AddExpand("data.subscriptions");. You can read more about expanding properties in lists here'